# What are the US tax implications of owning a controlling stake in a UK private limited company?

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, irs, corporation

I'm currently a US resident alien.

What are the tax implications of owning a controlling stake in a UK private limited company?

It is unclear how complex filing is and what financial implications are.

So my question is - how complex is the filing? What are the financial implications (even if no income is drawn)?

I have been reading this https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i5471 and it is unclear what category I'd even be filing under. (my suspicion is category 4)

I understand that as soon as income is received that must be declared and will be covered in the UK-US tax treaty to avoid double taxation.